# Hot to share common controllers action across other controllers in ZF?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Let us say I have a controller that takes care of login/registration/password recovery and such in my app. I want to share this across different modules and controllers. What's the best way?

Should I make an action helper, Or use inheritance? Of course I don't mean logic of those action, those are implemented by models (different for every module), I just want to share common parameters, interpretation and passing results to views.

I'm targeting to do some kind of a generic library for those things in my project. So I would have some abstract user model from which all other models that want to use login/registration function will inherit, but I'm wondering what about the controller stuff.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Basically I think  what you are trying to create are widgets . Here is an great article how to create them using action helper by ZF team lead http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html .

Answer (score 1):

Creating a re-usable authentication service is what you want to do. Creating it as a service allows you to test it in isolation. Inject the service into a front-controller plug-in so it is run during each request. The actual checking can be encapsulated into a custom validator so you can simply call ->isValid(). If not valid, re-route to the login page.

Comment: Could You supply any docs on how to create it more as an service in more detailed way. I know what You mean, but how to resolve it technicaly.